# Keyboard shortcuts to launch GNOME calculator in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-calculator

Is there are predefined keyboard shortcut for fast launch gnome-calculator?

When I try set custom (For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>) from settings they **doesn't work** for me:

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Prakash, I think Pratap's answer about gnome-calculator being a snap package (in a default 18.04 install) provides the reason.

Comment: In general question is a default shortcut for calculator. I think it must exist because some keyboards have a calculator key and must use some default shortcut.

Comment: @mature Ubuntu is slowly moving towards more snap. And I believe due to which although they changed the pre-installed gnome-calculator but somewhere forgot to change the inbuilt code for the calculator shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most shorter way is reinstall default snap calculator to deb:

```
sudo snap remove gnome-calculator
sudo apt install gnome-calculator
```

Then manual shortcuts from Settings starts working.

Answer (score 3):

The shortcut you are giving for *Launch calculator* is for gnome-calculator if you installed it via APT.

[image]

Below is the path of executable file of snap version of Calculator that is pre-installed with Ubuntu 18.04 which can be used to set shortcut as well.

```
/snap/bin/gnome-calculator
```

Output of `lsblk -lf`

```
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs                                            /snap/core/6130
loop1  squashfs                                            /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
loop2  squashfs                                            /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
loop3  squashfs                                            /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
loop4  squashfs                                            /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop5  squashfs                                            /snap/gnome-calculator/222
loop6  squashfs                                            /snap/gnome-characters/117
loop7  squashfs                                            /snap/gnome-system-monitor/54
loop8  squashfs                                            /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
loop9  squashfs                                            /snap/gnome-characters/139
loop10 squashfs                                            /snap/gnome-logs/40
loop11 squashfs                                            /snap/core/5328
loop12 squashfs                                            /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
loop13 squashfs                                            /snap/gnome-calculator/260
```

To use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> either install gnome-calculator from APT or create a custom shortcut for snap version of Calculator.

I have customized for both

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think if we use simply `gnome-calculator` in place of this long command, that should also work. by the way +1 to your answer since I noticed today in my virtualbox that the calculator pre-installed is now snap.

Comment: IIRC, there are about three applications installed as snaps by default in 18.04: gnome-calculator, system monitor, and something that shows characters such as emojis.

Comment: @DKBose I usually don't have anything installed in Ubuntu that I use in virtualbox. After running snap list I get 8 packages pre-installed, i.e. `core`, `core18`, `gnome-3-26-1604`, `gnome-calculator`, `gnome-characters`, `gnome-logs`, `gnome-system-monitor` , `gtk-common-themes`.

Comment: @PRATAP I've edited your answer to make it more clear. Also, Ubuntu software center provides snap version of calculator (at least in my main installation) so it is better to mention "APT" instead of software center. If you find some edit contradicting to your approach feel free to roll back the edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your Shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>) is used for another Keyboard Shortcuts?
Because when I set Shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>) for Gnome Calculator (on Ubuntu 18.10), it's run normally.
[keyboard shortcuts for gnome-calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTznt.png)

Maybe you need to "Reset All..." and set Shortcuts again.